# Unhandled promise rejection warning in Webpack, for Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

In an attempt to add a "server-side" state machine service to a single page application of Vue.js (cli), I edited following lines in webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:

```
  const app = this.app = new express(); // eslint-disable-line
  var globalStore ={ numRequests : 0  };

  // I added this by copy-pasting another app.all('/',..) request handler.
  app.all('/compute', (req, res, next) => { 
         globalStore.numRequests++;
         res.send("num request="+globalStore.numRequests);
         return next();   
  });
```

then it gave this warning each time counter is incremented:

> (node:12956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
>   [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client

Still, it increments the counter, returns it successfully everytime I visit {mydomainname}/compute. Everytime it gives same warning.

I guess I'm making a simple error but can't see. Project was produced by  this command:

```
vue init webpack vueapp01
```

If I delete "return next" and "res.send ('invalid host header')" lines, no warning is produced. Do I have to call "return" here always?

Comment: Why are you trying to do anything after the `return next();` call?

Comment: That was a left-over code fragment after a quick copy paste and a quick edit. It should'n work after return statement. Or does it run too?

Comment: It doesn't run, I just wanted to make sure that you weren't counting on it running or thinking that it did.

Comment: If I delete both  `return next` and `res.send(...)` line, no warnings is given. Maybe I don't have to pass the context to next middleware using next()? Is it wrong to cut the dataflow and response with a simple text instead? (If its meant to be done this way, logically?)

Comment: What about if you don't do any `res.send()` and instead just increment the `numRequests` and then immediately `next()`?  I think the `res.send()` is setting the `Content-Type` and possibly `Content-Length` which the next middlware might also be trying to do.  Consider [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send).  You may need to consider sending that data some other way.

Comment: Then an "express request handler" and a "client, ajax request" suits better for long-running jobs?

Comment: Well, a dedicated route that will provide the `globalStore.numRequests` might make more sense rather than trying to get in the way of the server's SPA routing.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think vuex store is better than these? (if storing is meant to wait for minutes at least for an operation, then return results)